# Tkinter/py2app program with a server to see data from another computer

Tags: python, tkinter, py2app

I have a tkinter program that I made and then turned it into a standalone app using py2app. Now I am looking to take it to the next level. I installed the app on another computer in my house and I was wondering if there was a way to link the two together and be able to access the data entered on one computer on the other.

For example, if I have this code:

```
counter = 0
def buttonPushed()
   global counter
   counter += 1

myButton = Button(window, text="enter", command=buttonPushed())
myLabel = Label(window, text= str(counter))
```

I want to be able to access what counter is equal too on one computer, from the other.

I am pretty new to tkinter and software developing so I am not really sure how to do this. Would I need to connect the two with some sort of server? If so how would I do this?

Again both computers are on the same network.

Comment: You can use TCP sockets.

Comment: Yes that would make sense, but how do I set that up?

Comment: You can go through this page https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-python/amp/

Comment: Thank you the page was very helpful. So would I need to set up the other computer as the client? And then how would I be able to see the data on one computer on the tkinter program?

Comment: Yes you need to run as client, you can add the client part in the tkinter program and read data from server